# Assigning numeric values to variables in PHP

Tags: php, numbers

I am trying to assign a variable the value of `01234` using PHP. But it keeps coming up with a different number. Why is it is displaying `668`?

```
$data = 01234;
echo $data;
```

The result I am getting is: `668`

Comment: Base 8 !!! `echo base_convert('01234', 8, 10);`.

Comment: Because it gets converted in octal value. Decimal integers don't have a leading 0

Comment: smells like a octal somewhere

Comment: Thank you  Damien Pirsy.

Comment: You can read up on the different types of numbers http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a leading zero is an instruction to parse it as an octal number, As having 0x as prefix means hex. [See the documentation for more information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

So this 01234 is parsed as octal and converted to decimal value which is 668.

Answer (score 2):

[From the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16),
>   octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a
>   sign (- or +).
>
> [...]
>
> **To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero)**. To use
>   hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary
>   notation precede the number with 0b.

You mistakenly specified the octal number `1234` (by adding the zero prefix) which equals `668` decimal.